# How to download partitioned hadoop files from Azure blob storage

Tags: csv, azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I am using HDInsight on Azure. I have outputted some Spark dataframes from Spark to CSV format on Azure Blob storage. I want to download these as single CSV files.

Spark has stored these as a empty files FOO.csv and a directory also called FOO.csv/ that contains the CSV partitions of the data.

Screenshots:

[[image: Spark output[1]]

[image: partitioned data]

On the head node of the HDInsight cluster I can merge the files locally using

```
$ hdfs dfs -getmerge wasb://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/salga2hf4da115242.csv salga2hf4da115242.csv
```

But this requires a running hadoop cluster to do this. I want to be able to get this data anywhere using the Azure CLI.

I tried this:

```
$ azure storage blob download cat-vectors-ru salga2hf4da115242.csv salga2hf4da115242.csv
```

But this only downloaded the 0 byte file in the top level of the container.

How can I download all the data with the Azure CLI? Is it possible for the Azure CLI to do the merge as well?

Comment: did you find any solutions? :)

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't, sorry. I had to settle with the hdfs method I outlined in the question to get my data out.